# jquery geocomplete plugin for multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, geocomplete

I am using the "geocomplete" JQuery library (http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/) for adding Google Places autocomplete to an online form, and populating hidden form fields with the returned data for the autocompleted address field.

Using the "form" example on the geocomplete site, I have this working well, and autocomplete is working, and populating all the form fields as expected.

However, I want to have TWO instances of this on the same page, so I can have an autocomplete for a start and end location.

I have both autocomplete fields added and both working. This is all fine.

The problem is that the jquery library populates only one set of input fields, with the returned Google data.

I cant see how to change this to fill in one set of fields for the start location, and another set of fields for the end location.

My jquery set up code is as follows:

```
$("#startgeocomplete").geocomplete({
details: "form",
types: ["geocode"],
country: 'gb'
});

$("#endgeocomplete").geocomplete({
details: "form",
types: ["geocode"],
country: 'gb'
});
```

And I have two input fields:

```
<input type="text" id="startgeocomplete" name="startlocation" value="pick-up location" />

<input type="text" id="endgeocomplete" name="endlocation" value="end location" />
```

And one set of hidden fields that are populated with the returned data from the Google autocomplete, eg:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lat" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="lng" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="formatted_address" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="postal_code" value="" />
```

Everything works as expected, but with only one set of fields to populate, when I enter the end location, it overwrites the data that was populated by the start location.

What I need to do is have TWO sets of hidden fields, eg:

```
<input type="hidden" name="start_postal_code" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="end_postal_code" value="" />
```

But I cant see how this is possible to do with this jquery library?

Any clues??

Comment: I have a potential hacky way to do this, by checking for either field changing value, and then populating "start_postal_code" if it was the start field that called the change, or "end_postal_code" if it was the end field that called the change. But that seems a messy way to do this!

Comment: What if you use a class instead of IDs? `$(".geocomplete").geocomplete({....` Also, why are you storing values in hidden input fields instead of keeping them in variables? Anyway you can populate two different forms using : `details: "#form1"` and `details: "#form2"`

Comment: I am storing the values in hidden fields, as this is part of a larger form, and it makes it easier to send everything to the next stage in one POST from the same form. Both autocomplete input fields are part of the same form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the documentation, it doesn't need 2 separate forms, just 2 separate `container`s so you can make the hidden fields for the start one in a `div` with id = `start` and `end` as `end` and then specify separate `detailsAttribute`

e.g. HTML

```
<input type="text" id="startgeocomplete" name="startlocation" value="pick-up location" />

<input type="text" id="endgeocomplete" name="endlocation" value="end location" />

<div id="start">
<input type="hidden" data-start="lat" name="start_lat" value="" />
<input type="hidden" data-start="lng" name="start_lng" value="" />
<input type="hidden" data-start="formatted_address" name="start_formatted_address" value="" />
<input type="hidden" data-start="postal_code" name="start_postal_code" value="" />
</div>

<div id="end">
<input type="hidden" data-end="lat"name="end_lat" value="" />
<input type="hidden" data-end="lng" name="end_lng" value="" />
<input type="hidden" data-end="formatted_address" name="end_formatted_address" value="" />
<input type="hidden" data-end="postal_code" name="end_postal_code" value="" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#startgeocomplete").geocomplete({
details: "start",
detailsAttribute: "data-start"
types: ["geocode"],
country: 'gb'
});

$("#endgeocomplete").geocomplete({
details: "end",
detailsAttribute: "data-end",
types: ["geocode"],
country: 'gb'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This didnt quite work, but it got me close, and I have a working solution now. Thank you!

Comment: @Richard would love to know how you got it working with multiple request. Create an answer to your own question if you could. thanks.

Comment: This answer does NOT work. @Richard would also like to know how  you got this working.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I got it working.

```
$("#startgeocomplete").geocomplete({
details: "form",
detailsAttribute: "data-start"
types: ["geocode"],
country: 'gb'
});

$("#endgeocomplete").geocomplete({
details: "form",
detailsAttribute: "data-end",
types: ["geocode"],
country: 'gb'
});
```

I changed the details to form on both and it works fine. Hop this helps.